# How to use mix of Regex and Exact literal match to fetch index value

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a dataframe which can be created from the code given below

```
 df2= pd.DataFrame({'level_0': ['No case 
 notes','Notes','1.Chinese','2.Widowed','No']})
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

I also have an input list which is given below

```
input_terms = ['No','Widowed','Chinese']
```

I would like to search these terms in dataframe and get their index.

How can I get my output to be like this

**[4,3,2]** -    #This is the output index list from dataframe for my input terms

As you can see, I don't want the result set include the terms 'No case notes','Notes' though they contains 'No' as part of its string - **Here I am doing a exact match**

But for the input terms 'Chinese' and 'Widowed', I want the result set to include '1.Chinese' and '2.Widowed' - **Here I am interested in something like str.contains method**

How can I apply a mix of exact and regex/str.contains approach to search a string?

Comment: How about `2.Chinese person`? If I search for `Chinese`, will that be in the results?

Comment: No, it will not be there...

Comment: Is possible distinguish which values are exact match and which not?

Comment: So you want to exactly match all the _letters_, but ignore all the other characters?

Comment: @Sweeper - yes, my input string (Chinese) should be the only letters in dataframe(1.Chinese). If yes,  then a match is found... If it had been 1.Chinese Person,  this will not be in the results

Comment: @Jezrael - no there is no way to distinguish... It is based on my input datatset and data also keeps changing often

Comment: @SELVA - is important order of values?

Comment: @jezrael - not sure whether I understood it right.  For example,  if my 1st input term is 'No' and it finds a match in dataframe at index 3, then I expect 3 to be the first element in output index list

Comment: @SELVA - I think my answer get different output - ordering is different of `[2,3,4]`.

Comment: I will try the solution and update it as soon as I am back to my desk

Comment: Both the solutions are working perfectly. But as I can mark only one of the answer as solution, I am going with the Sweeper's one as it's just one line of regex. Hope you are with me. Thank you both for the assistance and helping me learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*XXX[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

replace `XXX` with the search terms (remember to escape them!). For example:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*(?:Chinese|No|Widowed)[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

This is kind of a mix between `str.contains` and exact matches. It will basically ignore certain characters (in this case, everything that is not a-zA-Z), and do an exact match. If you want to ignore a different set of characters, just change the two character classes at the two ends. For example, if you want to ignore spaces as well:

```
^[^a-zA-Z\s]*XXX[^a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Comment: I tried the below approach to check for the input string is present but it doesn't work. "df2['level_0'].str.contains(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*x[^a-zA-Z]*$')", here x is the variable which contains my input term. As I have several records, I check element by element by using a for loop. However when I try "df2['level_0'].str.contains(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*No[^a-zA-Z]*$')", it works. How can I replace the search term with variable

Comment: @SELVA a simple way would be to do `str.contains(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*' + re.escape(x) + r'[^a-zA-Z]*$')`

Answer (score 2):

If order of index values is not important:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'level_0': ['No case notes','notes','1.Chinese','2.Widowed','No']})

input_terms = ['No','Widowed','Chinese']

pat = '|'.join(r"\d+\.{}$".format(x) for x in input_terms)
m1 = df2['level_0'].str.contains(pat)
m2 = df2['level_0'].isin(input_terms)

idx = df2.index[m1 | m2]
print (idx)
Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

If order is important:

```
input_terms = ['No','Widowed','Chinese']

out = []
for x in input_terms:
    a = df2.index[df2['level_0'] == x]
    b = df2.index[df2['level_0'].str.contains(r'\d+\.{}$'.format(x))]

print (out)
[4, 3, 2]
```